White growth on tree trunk and grass
There is a white growth (foamy or fungal/mushroom looking) on a large old tree in our new yard. It is at the base of the tree and has had black beetles on it that we sprayed. We have removed the growth but it came back. We are now spraying with a fungicide and it seems to be helping. What else should we do? There is a similar growth that had appeared on an indentation on our grass. I wonder if there had been a tree there that died, but don’t know. Northwest Arkansas area. I have been unable to post a picture.

Hi Pam, and welcome to the site!  This might help you post a picture.  https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798/how-to-post-images-here/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community Speaking of specifics - what is missing?  The tree's symptoms, the attempted treatment, and its results are described, and a question asking for alternative treatments.  This canned comment does not specify its specific problem with the post.  As it's currently writen, it's hard to tell exactly what it's asking for.

@MackM  What is missing and would be helpful is the type of tree and pictures

Given the usual pattern is "part of tree dies, fungus moves in" killing the fungus does not bring the dead part of the tree back from the dead, so "sucess" will be rather limited even if you completely eradicate the fungus (and you'll have all that lovely dead wood sitting there for some other fungus to colonize...)

A photo would have been very useful to be sure of diagnosis, but if the fungal growth is at the base of the tree trunk, then it's likely root rot and the tree is on its way out. The fungal growth which appears in the grass is likely related to the tree roots too, but the most important thing is to make sure the tree is still stable and not likely to fall over any time soon. You may wish to call an arborist or tree surgeon to inspect the tree to make sure it is safe. There is no point in treating the tree with anti fungicide, it will not save the tree, the obvious fungal activity is a sign the tree is dying.
If you are able to add a photo, please do so.
